# Чи можуть бути в одному реченні (та абзаці) різні часи?

Tags: синтаксис

Наратив оповідання ведеться в минулому часі. Нижче наводжу абзац з оповідання.

Головні поляни на схилі гори Гимба можна виобразити як неправильної форми бусини. Вони нанизані на бурчак, мов на волосінь, а сама поточина у самому підніжжі хребта гепається з бескиду, утворюючи тим самим знаменитий водоспад Шипіт. **Незважаючи на те, що величезна десятиметрова ватра в ніч на Івана Купала — це кульмінація однойменного водограю неформального фестивалю, далеко не всі пістряві девіанти перебували внизу: багато хто усе-таки лишився в таборах або тільки збирався спускатися удолину.** Були й ті, хто вже насолодились видовищем та нетвердим кроком верталися назад до своїх кустарних стоянок. Отим навіть тут, під рясним зводом лісу, тьмяно освічували шлях тріскучі осередки й факели.

Додатково хотілося б запитати, чи можна вживати після слів "Були й ті, хто..." дієслова у множині.
**Були й ті, хто вже насолодились видовищем та нетвердим кроком верталися назад до своїх кустарних стоянок.**

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в "*ватра в ніч на Івана Купала — це кульмінація*"? Але ж тут говориться не про теперешнє, а про цю ніч. Це дорівнює:
*Величезна десятиметрова ватра — це кульмінація в ніч на Івана Купала.* // Тобто можна переставляти, сенс не змінюється.
Тут визначення, а не дія.
Тут нема дієслова і нема помилки.

> чи можна вживати після слів "Були й ті, хто..." дієслова у множині

Чи правильне це запитання?
*Хто вже насолодились видовищем?* // Ні. Тому множина не підходить.